# R: Using dplyr to remove a column named in a string contained in a variable,

Tags: r, binding, scope, dplyr

I am creating a bunch of files. I have a list of two letter names. Each file includes a column with the same name as the file. I do a series of things to them, identifying both the file and the column with the name contained in a variable, sT. For example, I have a file called OH, and sT contains "OH".

The very last thing I want to do to the file is remove the eponymous column and return a file with the same name. I am trying to become fluent in *tidy*, language of the *tidyverse*, so I am trying to do this with select.

```
OH <- data.frame(X=1:2, OH=3:4)
```

I think this should work under nonstandard evaluation:

```
assign(sT, select(get(eval(sT)), -as.symbol(get(sT)))
```

where sT is "OH" and get(eval(sT)) is the file OH. And I think one of these should work, under standard evaluation:

```
assign(sT, select(get(eval(sT)), - sT))
```

or

```
assign(sT, select_(get(eval(sT)), paste0("-", sT)))
```

depending on whether `select_` will accept the minus sign inside of the string. But none of them do, returning respectively:

```
Error in -as.symbol(sT) : invalid argument to unary operator

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'OH' not found

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'OH' not found
```

Comment: You need to use the SE version: `get(sT) %>% select_(paste('-', sT))` All the `assign` and `eval` makes me think there's a better way to approach your larger goal, though.

Comment: Or with assignment, `assign(sT, get(sT) %>% select_(paste('-', sT)))` (assign doesn't seem to pipe well).

Comment: I think this is crying out for using a named `list` containing each of your datasets, but I'm not sure exactly what your bigger goal is. There is nothing 'tidy' about using `get` `assign` etc on free-floating `data.frames` and then adding a whole other level of complexity by running it through a pipe. I second @alistaire 's concerns that you probably shouldn't be using this strategy at all.

Comment: E.g. , you could do `bigl <- list(OH = data.frame(X=1:2, OH=3:4), NY = data.frame(X=1:2, NY=3:4))` to define a list and then `Map(function(ds, n) ds[-match(n,names(ds))], bigl, names(bigl) )` to remove the corresponding column from each list item. The original `bigl` can be usually created at the point of import via e.g. `lapply(listoffilenames, read.csv)` or something similar.

Comment: @alistaire I like  that! It's elegant. I want my code to look like that. However, it does not work..> get(sT) %>% select_(paste('-', sT))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'OH' not found
> str(OH)
'data.frame': 30448 obs. of  13 variables:

Comment: I still have not figured out how to do returns in the comment fields, sorry.

Comment: @alistaire I'm sure you're right that there is a better way. I have a column table with 13 variables for every county for every state for 23 years, which I supplement with a bunch of lookup tables, & it took me a while to get right for one state. All ultimately to draw a series of choropleth maps, for an animation. So now I'm trying to take this long ugly hack & replace the references to Ohio with something generic, to do my other 17 states.  What's really making me crazy is that I had this -- including this line -- working, & then I broke it, and I can not remember what it was like before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `matches`

```
assign(sT, select(get(eval(sT)), -matches(sT)))
```

Edit: as alistaire points out, it should be as below in case there are other columns whose names contain `OH`

```
assign(sT,select(get(eval(sT)), -matches(paste0('^', sT, '$'))))
```

Doing it as below is probably more readable. It's also faster.

```
assign(sT, OH[which(names(OH) != sT)])
```

If you want it as a function to `lapply` with here's one

```
removecol <- function(string, data = F){
    if(class(data) == 'logical') data <- get(eval(sT))
    assign(sT, data[which(names(data) != sT)], envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

OH
#  X OH
#1 1  3
#2 2  4
removecol(sT)
OH
#  X
#1 1
#2 2
```

Comment: If you have similarly-named variables, you may need to specify that's the whole name with `matches(paste0('^', sT, '$'))`

Comment: Thanks Jim! That did the job. One thing that fascinates me is seeing how better R programmers (i.e. most R programmers) write code that is shorter, cleaner, and more abstract than mine. I often still find such code hard to understand, but I am getting there. Like the gaciers, my progress is slow, but inexorable! At least, I hope I'm not going to exore it. This was the last missing bit for 1 state -- now I'm going to see if RStudio can turn my 6 pages of butt-ugly code into 1 function, that I can just hand to lapply with 18 2-letter state code & get out 18 animated maps. Fingers crossed.